# Indicating buffer size for XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, connection, buffer, xmlpullparser

I'm using XmlPullParser to load some data gradually over http on mobile devices.

Since the speed of such connections can often be as low as 1KB/s or less, I would like to lower the default Buffer size of 8096 bytes for the PullParser.

Do anybody have an idea, how that might be possible?
(Also, why does the PullParser even have its own buffer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you would need to set the buffer size of the Reader object or InputStream object passed to `XmlPullParser.setInput()`.

The setInput() method can accept either type of source but as both are abstract, the actual type of Reader or InputStream you use can vary - some may have buffers in which case you need to look at the docs to check depending on what you are using.

**EDIT:**

As for a class which implements XmlPullParser having a buffer - it seems to me that this is going to be inevitable as there will need to be a 'workspace' of some sort, but the size of the buffer and how that reflects on the amount of data requested from the Reader or InputStream each time, will come down to the class definition.

In conclusion, I would say the only way you will be able to control the amount of data requested each time is to define your own class which implements XmlPullParser. The easiest way would be to extend an open source class (such as the apache one) and simply override the methods that read from the Reader or InputStream sources (using a smaller buffer).

Comment: Do you mean XmlPullParser somehow ajusts its buffersize to the size of the rader it gets? But there is no way to know if a passed reader even has a buffer...?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: See me edits - I still think your answer may lie in controlling the reader/inputstream.

Comment: Well, I can say for sure that it is the XmlPullParser requesting chucks of size 4k or 8k. I don't know what implementation Android uses, but if they use the apache one: http://goo.gl/ScVr6 it clearly instantiates a buffer of size 8096. This seams ridiculous for a networking tool that already relies on a likely to be buffered Reader. There  must be some way around it..

Comment: @Thomas Ahle : OK, see my last edit. This is the only suggestion I can come up with.

Comment: I believe you are right. I've taken the Kxml parser into my project. It allows better configuration of buffer size. There seams to be a lot of parsers out there, but I haven't been able to find a recent speed comparison.